# Dynamic inner html by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a event calendar with wednesday **week header** like

```
<th class="fc-day-header fc-wed fc-widget-header">Wed</th>
```

and **days**

```
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2014-02-26">
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-03-05">
```

I Want to append some texts to the inner html of **days**. When tried the following codes

```
    var items = "SWERTY LOPES-014-256-9696",
    divs = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-wed');
    [].slice.call( divs ).forEach(function ( div ) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML+items;    
    });
```

it changed the **days** and **week header** too. But i want **weak header** inner html remains unchanged.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to target only td elements with the said class

```
var items = "SWERTY LOPES-014-256-9696",
    divs = document.querySelectorAll('td.fc-wed');
[].slice.call(divs).forEach(function (div) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + items;
});
```

---

since tagged with jQuery

```
var items = "SWERTY LOPES-014-256-9696";
$('td.fc-wed').html(function (i, html) {
    return html + items
})
```